# Does Cirq support GPU acceleration?

Tags: programming, cirq

I'm wondering if Cirq does (or plans to) support GPU acceleration of matrix operations, including density matrix simulations. I would like to speed up training and evaluations of variational circuits under different noise conditions when GPUs are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cirq](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq)'s mainline doesn't have this but you can use [cirq-qulacs](https://github.com/qulacs/cirq-qulacs); which has a Variational Quantum Circuit Simulator and supports CUDA for high performance simulation.

Comment: This is probably the solution in the near term. It would be nice to know if there are plans to eventually support this in the mainline development.

Comment: We currently don't have GPU support on the road map. If you'd like this in the mainline, please file a [feature request](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/master/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/feature_request.md). If cirq-qulacs doesn't meet your needs, please mention that in the feature request.